# Premiere sometimes not rendering 4k MXF files from Sony FS5

Tags: premiere, 4k, mxf

I'm working in 4k for the first time.  I've got footage from a variety of sources, and I'm working on a 4k timeline (see sequence settings below).

When I try to render between In and Out points, I get the following error when Premiere gets to certain MXF files.  All the MXF files came from a Sony FS5 camera, shooting in one of the flatter "log" picture modes (can't remember exact setting).

It renders some of them fine, but some I had to reconvert into ProRes.

I'd like to work directly from the MXF files if possible.

I'm using a 2015 MacBook Pro 16GB RAM, OS X 10.11.6 with Adobe Creative Cloud 2015, Premiere version 2015.4 release, v.10.4.0(30) build.

Error message when I try to render in Premiere:
[image]

Error message from Media Encoder:
[image]

Sequence settings:
[image]

Problematic clip properties below:

```
Clip0019.MXF
Type: MXF 
File Size: 2.76 GB
Image Size: 3840 x 2160
Frame Rate: 25.00
Source Audio Format: 48000 Hz - 24 bit - 4 channels
Project Audio Format: 48000 Hz - 32 bit floating point - 4 channels
Total Duration: 00:03:58:14
Pixel Aspect Ratio: 1.0

MXF File details:
Wrapper type: MXF OP1a (type: SingleItem SinglePackage MultiTrack Stream Internal)
File generated by: Sony, Mem  (2.00)
H.264/MPEG-4 AVC Long GOP High Profile 4:2:0 Unconstrained Coding
```

Comment: Try remuxing it : `ffmpeg -i in.mxf -c copy out.mxf`

Answer (score 0):

Premiere supports MXF container file formats with the following formats
P2 Movie: Panasonic Op-Atom variant of MXF video in DV, DVCPRO, DVCPRO 50, DVCPRO HD, AVC-Intra
Sony XDCAM HD 18/25/35 (4:2:0)
Sony XDCAM HD 50 (4:2:2)
AVC-LongGOP
XAVC Intra
XAVC LongGOP
JPEG2000
IMX 30/40/50
XDCAM EX

Comment: This is not a complete answer in that it does not address the 4K question.  I don't have a SONY F5 so cannot test, but I suspect that Pro CC 2017 (not 2015) probably does support the MXF format of the SONY F5.  Thus, the correct answer is probably "upgrade PPro CC 2015 to PPro CC 2017".  But again, I cannot test it as I don't have the proper source material.

Comment: This is what I did, and 2017 does appear to have fixed the issue.